# Response not loading when using utf-8 chars in header with spring-boot rest and Swagger

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I have spring boot-application with swagger. When I am testing my rest services with no utf-8 chars in header everything works OK. Swagger generate command which I can use to test it:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'user: me' --header 'reason: zst' --header 'Authorization: Basic dG9tYXM6dG9tYXMxMjM=' 'http://localhost:8080/my-app/uuid/756531B55A3D029A0894D7C9C4ACDF3EC0'
```

but when I am using utf-8 chars in swagger I got no response. Swagger is just loading something. When I look into console of firefox I see just some get request:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/throbber.gif
```

without response.

When I try to edit `curl` command above:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'user: me' --header 'reason: žšť' --header 'Authorization: Basic dG9tYXM6dG9tYXMxMjM=' 'http://localhost:8080/my-app/uuid/756531B55A3D029A0894D7C9C4ACDF3EC0'
```

everything works OK so I guess there is no problem with my backend. Is there some way how I can fix/debug this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**RFC 2616 section 4**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), **Message Headers** are defined as follows:

```
message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                 and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                 of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

Knowing that according to the [**section 2**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html):

```
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
quoted-string  = ( <"> *(qdtext | quoted-pair ) <"> )
qdtext         = <any TEXT except <">>
```

> The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values
>   that are not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. **Words
>   of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than `ISO-8859-1` only when encoded according to the rules of [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)**.

```
TEXT          = <any OCTET except CTLs,
                but including LWS>
```

---

In other words, the value of an header can only be `ISO-8859-1` encoded, if you want to encode characters that are not included into this charset which seems to be the case here, you are supposed to encode it according to the **RFC 2047** also known as *MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text*.

**So instead of**

```
reason: žšť
```

**It should be**

```
reason: =?utf-8?q?=C5=BE=C5=A1=C5=A5?=
```

In practice, it is even recommended to encode the value when you don't have only `US-ASCII` characters.

The last thing to check on your side, is if your JAX-RS implementation supports out of the box the **RFC 2047**, if not you will need to decode it manually for example using the utility method [`MimeUtility.decodeText(String etext)`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText-java.lang.String-).

**Here is a concrete example:**

```
@GET
public Response showHeader(@HeaderParam("reason") String reason) 
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // Decode it
    reason = MimeUtility.decodeText(reason);
    // Return the value of the decoded String
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
        .entity(String.format("Value of reason = '%s'", reason))
        .build();
}
```

Calling this *resource method* using **curl** with `--header 'reason: =?utf-8?q?=C5=BE=C5=A1=C5=A5?='` gives as expected:

```
Value of reason = 'žšť'
```

**NB:** To encode your header's value from your js front-end, you could use the library [**q-encoding**](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/q-encoding), here is a [live demo](https://mothereff.in/q).

Comment: thx man nice answer. I will get your reward as soon as possible. Just one additional question. As frontend we are using angular. Is there some method which can encode this text according to RFC you mention above ?